# Flex chart axis title blinking on resize

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, flex-charting

I am having a chart with titles for horizontal and vertical axis. the verticalAxisTitleAlignment property of the vertical axis renderer is set to vertical. The application is a portal sort of thing and this chart is placed inside a small window. on click of the window am resizing the parent of the chart. but at that time the title of the axis is blinking and it provides a feeling that the resizing is not smooth. I dont understand why this happens? does the tile renders each time when the component is maximized? is there any way to stop that?

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers, PK

This is the code am using to draw the title :

```
<mx:horizontalAxis>
 <mx:LinearAxis id="haxis" title="Share" interval="5"/>
</mx:horizontalAxis>
<mx:verticalAxis>
 <mx:LinearAxis id="vaxis" title="{'Aided'+ '\n'+ '    awareness'}" interval="5"/>
</mx:verticalAxis>
<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
 <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{haxis}" 
  axisStroke="{axisStroke}"
  tickPlacement="none"/>
</mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
 <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{vaxis}" 
  axisStroke="{axisStroke}" 
  verticalAxisTitleAlignment="vertical"
  tickPlacement="none"/>
</mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```

Answer (score 0):

> does the tile renders each time when
>   the component is maximized?

Yes it does. That's how iteRenderer works.

> is there any way to stop that?

Can you show your itemRenderer code.

Comment: Thnx for the reply Vinoth. I had added the code snippet in my question. Am not using any item renderer. simple title and its alignment. But am still seeing the blinking :(